# Restricting IP Address in Google maps API not working

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I've set up a key in google maps api, and restricted it to a specific ip.
This IP is the IP of my online website (I got it with 'ping XXX.com' in CMD).

I only send API requests off my server-side.

When I try to send, it fails. But when I emit the IP Address restriction, it successes.
So it seems that the IP is wrong.

This is where I restrict it:
[image]

Comment: Do you have something running between your server and googlemaps api? Like cloudflare or something?

Comment: @AvivLo No, There is nothing.

Comment: Do you have a ssh access to your server?

Comment: @AvivLo YES indeed

Comment: try ssh into it run the following command `curl ipinfo.io/ip` which is going to get your external ip and try to use that instead.

Comment: Is there any specific error that the API returned? Can you also give us a sample API request?